# Is there an equivalent to the Windows 7 Problem Steps Recorder on macOS?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, development

Is there an equivalent to the [Windows 7 Problem Steps Recorder](http://tech.icrontic.com/article/20-new-features-in-windows-7/#attachment_28222) on macOS and or iOS?

Comment: You could try having them do a screen recording with command+shift+5. If you want to see keystrokes, try to have them have the keyboard viewer on the screen: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/show-on-screen-keyboard-macos-sierra

I don't know enough about problem recorder, but if you do think this is a good answer, lmk and I'll post it below for the bounty.

Comment: @TalosPotential that sounds like some help. I encourage you to post regardless of bounty system.

Comment: @Marco There's no built-in solution but would you be interested in a 3rd-party app to do this?

Comment: @ankii I wasn't sure if it counted as a full answer, but I guess I can try

Comment: @fsb. No, thanks, it is not 'that' necessary. Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to use video recording, I often press Command+Shift+4 and take a screenshot of every step. The screenshot names will reflect the time they were taken so they maintain order of execution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try having them do a screen recording with command+shift+5. If you want to see keystrokes, try to have them have the keyboard viewer on the screen:

- [laptopmag.com/articles/show-on-screen-keyboard-macos-sierra](http://laptopmag.com/articles/show-on-screen-keyboard-macos-sierra)

For iOS, swipe up to get control centre and tap the icon with a dot in a circle. It starts recording in 3 seconds and can be stopped using the red strip on the top. Video will be saved to photos.

Answer (score -1):

No. ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I am having a hard time finding reasons for how is this better than not answering? Don't blame me for removing the clutter around it in the edit, but is this really all you had to say?

Comment: @ankii I’m more inclined to blame the question when someone asks a yes/no question. Not the answerer. Since this is a software recommendation question and broad, the question could be voted closed quite easily until it explains a bit what the functions of the tool are explicitly.

Comment: @bmike **1** I tried VTC-ing it.. but bounty stops us non-diamond people. Didn't feel a lot for flagging for ending the bounty. **2** If Marco wants, better ask a new question, put details and then close this as the new one's dupe. **3** I anyway don't understand the purpose of putting a bounty on an inadequate question and moreover never coming back to give feedback. **4** the question was from 2011, answer came in 2012, [software rec policy](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180) came in 2014. I am not aware of other faq.