# Is there an equivalent to Problem Step Recorder (PSR) for OS X?

Tags: macos, applications, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent to the Windows 7 Problem Steps Recorder on MacOSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-windows-7-problem-steps-recorder-on-macosx)

I would like to find an application that reproduces the functionality of PSR on OS X as closely as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Having only become aware of PSR from this post and some minor sleuthing, I can't speak to it's full functionality.  The main task of screen recording can be accommodated by [using Quicktime](http://www.sampletheweb.com/2009/09/04/how-to-use-snow-leopards-new-quicktime-screen-recording-feature-to-record-hulu-content-for-your-iphone/) (this example has a few unnecessary steps at the beginning but you'll ge the idea.)  If you need additional diagnostic information from log files, point the user to the Console application in the `/Applications/Utilities` folder.

If there's additional functionality I didn't glean that you require, please let us know!

Comment: PSR goes way beyond what the Quicktime Screen Recording is capable of. One of it's primary functions is to detect a mouse click, capture the screen at that moment, highlight where the mouse click occurred in the screen shot, and record other details about the mouse click.

It makes it easy for another user to perform the same set of actions at the one who did it to begin with. The Quicktime Screen Capture comes close, but the capabilities of PSR are far greater.