# Auto grab a window screenshot on each mouse click Mac

Tags: macos, applescript, automation, screen-capture

Is it possible to Applescript an autotake of a screenshot in an app on every mouse click without need to press Cmd+Shift+4->Click every time?

Comment: How do you envisage this actually functioning? Your mouse would be incapable of any other interaction & you'd still have to define your screenshot area each time [which also needs the mouse]. Cmd/Shift 5 would let you predefine an area, but requires Enter to actually take the shot. If you have a multi-button mouse, you could persuade one of the other buttons to send a pre-defined key command.

Comment: On a semantical note, could we get you to post an [edit] to the question with a practical and specific question?  "Is it possible?" tends to have a binary answer and as explained by @Tetsujin, it is in fact possible.  However, were do we go from here?  Can you share what you've attempted, where you got stuck, what failed, etc?

Comment: I envision it as opening an Enjoy Sudoku app and have it save screenshot on each click in a specified folder as I play it to create a gif of the gameplay. 

How to define area? Window. How to do anything else in the meantime? Restrict the action to the window. 

I do not understand why is my question encountering such fury and edits.

Comment: Related: [macos - Is there an equivalent to Problem Step Recorder (PSR) for OS X? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48504/is-there-an-equivalent-to-problem-step-recorder-psr-for-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

No - AppleScript doesn't hook into the GUI stream on macOS so you'd need a different item/app/tool to perform this function.

Since [you've asked an XY problem type question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - feel free to [research a bit about that and ask a follow on question to describe the problem and more importantly - what research you've done (add links) and why that research isn't solving the main issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

- maybe you only have one app that needs this
- maybe you don't need every mouse click / just ones in one window
- maybe you have a thing you'll do with these images and we can help solve that deeper problem without needing scripting or an extensible app or a general solve